# Problem with useState, UseEffect when saving data when getting data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, axios, react-hooks

I am new to react native and I want on the welcome screen of my application to click on a request to an api using axios and the data is saved in a variable using useState and then use this data in another class (AllProductCategory .js) without having to make the request back to the api.

I am using React native 0.62 hooks react navigation 5 and axios.

I have the following in the Navigation.js file. A context that has a useMemo as its value, which contains a return so that it returns an array with information that it brings from an application using axios. the class looks like this:
In this class skip certain lines of code that have nothing to do with the problem I am currently having.

```
export default function Navigation() {
  const [allproducts, setAllproducts] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const _loadAllCategories = async () => {
      await axiosClient
        .get("/service/product_available")
        .then(function (response) {
          console.log("Data antes de pasarlo al useState ", response.data);
          setAllproducts(response.data);
          console.log("Los productos son: ", allproducts);
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
          console.log("Error obteniendo el token", error);
        });
    };
    _loadAllCategories();
  }, []);

  const authContext = useMemo(
    () => ({
      getAllProducts: () => {
        return allproducts;
      },
    }),
    []
  );

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={authContext}>
      {state.isLoading ? (
        <SplashStackScreen />
      ) : state.userToken == null ? (
        <PrincipalStackScreen />
      ) : (
        <MyDrawer />
      )}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

With this file what I want is for the data that brings all the products to be loaded when the splash screen is loading and so when I want to use this data on another screen, just call the context variable and return the data without having to make another request to the api.

Then in the class I implement the call of this data using the context

```
const { getAllProducts } = React.useContext(AuthContext);
const allProducts = getAllProducts();
```

The complete class is like this:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { View, Text, FlatList, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity, Dimensions, Image } from "react-native";
import { AuthContext } from "../../context";

var { height, width } = Dimensions.get("window");

export default function AllProductCategoryScreen() {
  const { getAllProducts } = React.useContext(AuthContext);
  const allProducts = getAllProducts();

  function Product_Category({ name, image }) {
      console.log("name e image", name);
    return (
      <View>
        <TouchableOpacity>
          <Image style={styles.imageCategory} source={{ uri: image }} />
          <Text>{name}</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  }

  return (
    <View>
      <Text>Todas las categorias</Text>
      <View style={{ alignItems: "center" }}>
        <FlatList
          scrollEnabled={true}
          numColumns={2}
          data={allProducts}
          renderItem={({ item }) => (
            <Product_Category name={item.name} image={item.imagePath} />
          )}
          keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
        />
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}
```

My app.js is as follows:

```
import React from 'react';
import Navigation from "./src/components/Navigation/Navigation"

export default function App() {
  return <Navigation />
}
```

The problem that I currently have is that when I start my app, I show that the request is made with axios and it brings the data correctly, however the useState is not filled with the data that the axios responds to me (it prints []). However if I save changes being in the navigation.js class in visual code the variable allproducts of the navigation class is filled with the data correctly and therefore in the other class where I want to display the data, it paints the data correctly.

I need that when my app loads, the data that the api brings is saved and that when using it in the other class, these data remain so that they can be used and illustrate this data on the screen.

Comment: Why do you need the `useMemo`?

Comment: @RossAllen In the use memo I have other options that make use of a dispatch for a reducer that I have, this for the whole topic of authentication in the app.
If there is a better way to do what I want to do, I would appreciate it if you could tell me what it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the function passed to `useMemo` is created, it captures the first value of `allproducts` and will always have that value. It will always return `[]`.

In order for `useMemo` to run again and capture a new value, add that value to the second argument, the array. React will call the memo function whenever a value in that array changes, and then `getAllProducts` will be created again and capture a new value of `allproducts`.

```
 const authContext = useMemo(
    () => ({
      getAllProducts: () => {
        return allproducts;
      },
    }),
    [allproducts]
  );
```

Comment: Excellent, thank you very much that has served me. I take advantage and I ask you, if you want to use this useMemo to use it together with a useReducer, could it use and could it be a better way of doing things?

Comment: I'm not clear on what you're asking? Could you elaborate?

Comment: I ask that if the way I'm doing it is the best way to get the data to be loaded into a home to use it on later screens

Comment: I understand. I suggest you check our a more robust state management library like [Redux](https://redux.js.org/) if you want to maintain state across navigating pages.